# Next.js Environment Variables Can Be Logged But Not Used During Execution

Tags: next.js, supabase

When I log my `process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY`, it is defined but when my code executes, it is missing. If I hard code the service role key, the code runs as expected here -

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL;
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;
const supabaseServiceKey = process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY;

export const supabasePublic = createClient(
  supabaseUrl,
  supabaseAnonKey
);

console.log("supabaseServiceKey: ", supabaseServiceKey);

if (!supabaseServiceKey) {
  throw new Error("Missing SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY");
}

export const supabasePrivate = createClient(
  supabaseUrl,
  supabaseServiceKey
);
```

But if I switch to fetching the service key from an environment variable it's missing when the code executes.

So if I'm using the environment variable and I refresh my the page in my Next.js project, which was run from `npm run dev` then `supabaseServiceKey` is logged with the key. But then I hit the `Missing SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY` error.

The execution path is:

```
/pages/checkout (client-side)  
/src/services/balance (client-side)  
/pages/api/get-balance (server-side)  
/src/utils/supabase/fetch-row (server-side, because it's imported into an API route)  
/src/utils/supabase/create-client (server-side, because it's imported into an API route)
```

What's even more strange is a [message](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/supabase/issues/188) is logged after the error is thrown which implies that the Supabase client was created successfully.

Comment: You can read about nextjs env vars here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

The gist is that env variables prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_ will be embedded in your code in clear text and are therefore visible on the client-side. Anything else will only be visible in secure server-side environments.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the variables server-side so I don't think that applies here?

Comment: I can't answer this without seeing your full code. However in general it would be best to separate your admin client creation from your browser client creation, you seem to be having it in one file, which might be causing the issue here. But difficult to day without more code.

Comment: @thorwebdev appreciate the pointer, I'll trying splitting the files.

Comment: Update - this is now sorted. I had made a mistake in my component logic and was executing server-side logic from a client-side component.

Answer (score 0):

use [t3-env](https://env.t3.gg/docs/nextjs) in the future to avoid errors like this.